# Data sent over ROS2 topic is not reliable

Tags: ros2, sensors, ros-humble, computer-vision, rostopic

Hello everyone of this wonderful forum. I am currently doing my first ROS2 project in which i have send data of aruco id that includes its [id number,x,y,z,orientation] data. I am sending this data over pre-defined ros2 topic of "std_msgs.msg Float64MultiArray". But when there are more than aruco boxes the data keeps shifting position like this

[image]

[image]

any suggestions on how to resolve this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Having only one topic means all detected marker poses will be published on this topic, which results in the pose inconsistency you experienced. The topic carries all markers poses.

**How to solve this issue?**

Those markers have unique IDs. You need to have as many topics as the unique markers. Let's say the topic names follow the pattern `marker_X_pose`, X is the exact ID.

When you have a marker detected, first check its ID and then publish its pose on the corresponding topic. This ensures single marker pose per topic, and will solve the issue you experienced. Hope this helps!

Comment: so u are advicing me to have different topics for different aruco ids and from that extract their information. Am i right? pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: **Yes**, use a single topic to carry each aruco marker pose. It is good to start simple. Use only one marker and there will be no problem. Add two markers, and the problem shows up. Add another topic and decide which topic to publish based on the marker ID.

Comment: but in this project number of aruco and its id are spawned at random so then for such scenario this suggestion does not seem feasible. Can there be any other general solution to this problem?